# How to attach created php excel to another function

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

I need to pass the gerenrated PHPExcel output to a function that will send it via Email. My current code is this:

```
        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5'); 
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    //Send Email here 

    $this->ciEngine->load->library( 'Services\Notifications\PushReports\Survey\Email' );
    $emailResult = $this->ciEngine->Email->emailSurvey();
```

**UPDATE
*I'm adding the emailSurvey's code for reference.*

```
namespace Services\Notifications\PushReports\Survey;

use \Services\ServiceBase;

class Email
    extends ServiceBase
{
    public function emailSurvey( $countryConfig, $appointment )
    {
    if( empty( $appointment ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    $this->ciEngine->load->library( 'email' );
        $receipient     = $this->ciEngine->config->config['push-report-receipient'];
        $sender = $this->ciEngine->config->config['push-report-sender'];


    if( !empty($receipient) && !empty($sender) ){
    $this->ciEngine->email->initialize( $this->ciEngine->config->config );
    $this->ciEngine->email->from( $sender );
    $this->ciEngine->email->to( $receipient );

    $this->ciEngine->email->subject( $this->ciEngine->config->config['push-report-subject'] );
    ob_start();
    $this->ciEngine->load->view( 'emails/surveyPush' );
    $mailBody = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    $this->ciEngine->email->message( $mailBody );
    return $this->ciEngine->email->send();
    }
}
```

}

How could I pass it to the emailSurvey function?

Comment: is `Services\Notifications\PushReports\Survey\Email` some custom mail service?

Comment: @Vini yes this is a semi customized mail service using codeigniter libraries. We tweaked it a bit but it should still utilize the same way as a regular email is created. I'll add the function's code as an update.

Comment: Well, if it is custom function what is the reason behind not writing additional method for sending email with attachment? With that code you can not add file to mail.